# How to programmatically set IP address on Windows 7 using C

Tags: c, windows-7, ip-address

I am developing an application that requires the ability to be able to set the IP address.

Using command prompt

Netsh interface IP set address....

It works but what is the equivalent in c?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need AddIPAddress() API.

Refer to [AddIPAddress function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365801(v=vs.85).aspx) at MSDN documentation with a good example.

You can refer to a majority of networking APIs (query, set, delete IPs etc) at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366071(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use system command in c which is a very helpful command in executing command prompt commands.for ex system('watever command you can type here');

Comment: In Windows, that should always be a last resort.  Use the API wherever possible.  Also, `netsh interface` is deprecated.

Comment: -1 because of pointing the OP to misdirection. Spawning another process and then parsing the output isn't much of a solution at all, it's more like example of bad programming