# Is it possible to change my IP address with C in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I want to change my IP address in Window with C, but only things I can find is the function like inet_pton(), or doing with C++. Can I use the latter with C or should I make some difference? If so, how should I do?

Comment: Why? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you think changing the IP address of some interface is the solution to that problem?

Comment: Probably a lot easier with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the IP address of a network interface by program, you should find the correct Windows' system call.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33867268/7865574